# Optimal way to convert `QByteArray` to `std::vector<char>`?

Tags: c++, qt, c++17

I am trying to move the data from `QByteArray` to `std::vector<char>` with as less overhead as possible.

I found 4 ways so far, which one's performance is the best? Is there better solution? Which one would you like to see in code review?

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <vector>

int main() {

    auto b = QByteArray("hello");
    std::vector<char> v;

    // 1
    v = std::vector<char>(*b.data(),b.size());

    // 2
    v = std::vector<char>(b.begin(),b.end());

    // 3
    std::move(b.begin(),b.end(),std::back_inserter(v));

    // 4
    v.resize(b.size());
    std::memcpy(&v[0],b,b.size());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user1095108 no.2 is almost certainly going to reserve enough space to start, since `QByteArray::iterator` is random access.  There's no real reason to do it yourself.

Comment: No. 1 does not do what you think it does. No. 3 ... doesn't do what you think it does, even more.

Comment: @MilesBudnek: Correct, except on one minor point: it's not just "almost certain...". It's *required* behavior: "Makes only N calls to the copy constructor of T (where N is the distance between first and last) and no reallocations if iterators first and last are of forward, bidirectional, or random access categories." (§[vector.cons]/10). The lack of reallocation directly implies that it must reserve sufficient space before copying elements.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Oh, nice.  I always assumed any standard lib worth its salt would make such an optimization, but I didn't realize the standard mandated no reallocations.  Good to know.

Comment: std::vector<char> v(b.cbegin(), b.cend()); this is so that b does not detach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just initialize the vector using the `cbegin` and `cend` iterators from your `QByteArray`:

```
int main() {
    QByteArray b("hello");
    std::vector<char> v(b.cbegin(), b.cend());
}
```

This will copy the data from `b` into `v` and is as optimal as you can get.

It's important to use `cbegin` and `cend` since `QByteArray` uses copy-on-write to avoid copying its underlying data when the object is copied until one of the copies has some potentially-modifying operation done to it.  Since data can be modified via the iterators returned by the non-const `begin` and `end` methods they could cause the data to be copied an extra time if the `QByteArray` you're copying from has itself been previously copied.

Since `QByteArray::iterator` is a random access iterator `v` will automatically pre-allocate enough space before copying the data from `b`, so there's no need to manually `reserve` space.

Also, since `char` is a trivial type there's no benefit to using `std::move`.